# How to hide field from Stakeholders in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

Is there a way which permits to hide certain fields from the users which possess Stakeholder access level licence or belong to certain groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. All fields are visible to anyone who has access to view the work item.

This applies to both the work item form and the REST APIs.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks, I updated my answer to include that tidbit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, Daniel!

Comment: Quick question: can I use another form which will not have the hidden fields?